# Is there a way to clear everything after making bodies on matter.js?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I'm new to both matter.js and js.
This is quite basic question, but I have been stuck in this problem for 8 hours already.

I want to clear the canvas and restart the whole event from the scratch when the pile of objects reach the top of the browser.

But I don't know how to add it to my code below. 
Please help me.

Here is my code.

```html
<html><body>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.14.2/matter.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script>

// 윈도우(브라우저)의 크기를 변수에 담습니다.
const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
 
// Matter-js
const Engine = Matter.Engine;
const Render = Matter.Render;
const World = Matter.World;
const Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
const Events = Matter.Events;
const Common = Matter.Common;
const MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;
const Composites = Matter.Composites;
// 이 밖에도
// console.log(Matter); 를 찍어보면 알 수 있듯이
// Composite, Constraint, Mouse ... 등 많은 기능들이 있습니다.
// 이 부분은 다음 글에서 천천히 추가적으로 정리해보려 합니다.
 
// 엔진을 생성합니다.
const engine = Engine.create();
const world = engine.world;
engine.world.gravity.y = 0.3;
// engine.world.gravity 는 중력?? 이라고 해야하나 y축으로 떨어지는 속도를 정합니다.
// 0 보다 작으면 오브제들이 위로 올라갑니다.
// engine.world.gravity.x 속성도 있어서 오른쪽 또는 왼쪽으로 쏠리게 할 수도 있습니다.
 
// Bodies에서 오브제를 만듭니다.
// 이름 그대로 circle은 원, rectangle은 사각형을 만듭니다.
// 자세한 정보는 공식 홈페이지를 참고하는게 더 좋을 것 같지만
// Bodies.circle(x축 위치값, y축 위치값, 반지름값, 옵션);
// Bodies.rectangle(x축 위치값, y축 위치값, 너비값, 높이값, 옵션);
// 입니다.
// const stack = Composites.stack(0, 0, 20, 20, (windowWidth-(20*40))/9, (windowHeight-(20*40))/9, function(x, y) {
//     return Bodies.circle(x, y, 40, { 
//       friction: 0.7,
//       frictionStatic: 10,
//       restitution: 0.2,
//       slop: 1,
//       render: {
//       fillStyle: ["#FE5442", "#FFE100", "#3F43AD", "#00AC8C"][Math.round(Math.random() * 3)]
//     }
//   });
// });

const circle = Bodies.circle(windowWidth/2, 50, windowWidth*0.04, {
      // friction: 0.2,
      // restitution: 0.8,
        render: {
          fillStyle: '#FE5442'
        }
        // fillStyle 은 채워질 색, strokeStyle은 선색, lineWidth 선 굵기
      });
const ground = Bodies.rectangle(windowWidth/2, windowHeight+1, windowWidth, 1, {
        isStatic: true
        // 고정된 위치의 오브제
      });
// 이 밖에 options 값들이 어떤것들이 있는지 아직 다 잘 알지 못해서, 공부해서 추후에 자세히 추가하겠습니다.
 
const leftSide = Bodies.rectangle(windowWidth+1, windowHeight/2, 1, windowHeight, {
  isStatic: true, 
  render: {
    fillStyle: '#ffffff'
  }
});

const rightSide = Bodies.rectangle(-1, windowHeight/2, 1, windowHeight, {
  isStatic: true, 
  render: {
    fillStyle: '#ffffff'
  }
});

// World에 위 오브제들을 추가합니다.
World.add(engine.world, [circle, ground, leftSide, rightSide]);
 
// 렌더를 생성합니다.
const render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine,
    options: {
      width: windowWidth,
      height: windowHeight,
      // 기본값은 wireFrames 값이 ture이고 false를 주지 않으면 
      // 위에 작성한 Bodies.circle의 render 옵션이 적용되지 않습니다.
      wireframes: false,
      background: '#fff'
    }
});
 
// 엔진을 실행하고
Engine.run(engine);
// 렌더를 실행합니다.
Render.run(render);
 
 
// 몇가지 이벤트를 추가합니다.
 
// render 객체의 canvas는 DOM body에 추가 될 canvas 엘리먼트를 가리킵니다.
render.canvas.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // 캔버스를 마우스로 클릭하면
  // 현재 마우스 위치에 반지름이 10인 원을 만들어서
  const box = Bodies.circle(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, windowWidth*0.04, {
    // friction: 0.2,
    // restitution: 0.8,
    render: {
    fillStyle: ["#FE5442", "#FFE100", "#3F43AD"][Math.round(Math.random() * 2)]
    }
  });
  // 공간에 추가합니다.
  World.add(engine.world, box);
}, false);

 
// 1초 간격으로
setInterval(() => {
  // 가로 중앙, 상단에서 50px 떨어진 곳에 반지름이 10인 원을 만들어서
  const box = Bodies.circle(Common.random(0, windowWidth), 50, windowWidth*0.04, {
    // friction: 0.2,
    // restitution: 0.8,
    render: {
    fillStyle: ["#FE5442", "#FFE100", "#3F43AD"][Math.round(Math.random() * 2)]
    }
  });
  // 공간에 추가합니다.
  World.add(engine.world, box);
}, 1000);

setInterval(() => {
  // 가로 중앙, 상단에서 50px 떨어진 곳에 반지름이 10인 원을 만들어서
  const box2 = Bodies.rectangle(Common.random(0, windowWidth), 50, windowWidth*0.08, windowWidth*0.08, {
    // friction: 0.2,
    // restitution: 0.8,
    render: {
    fillStyle: ["#FE5442", "#FFE100", "#3F43AD"][Math.round(Math.random() * 2)]
    }
  });
  // 공간에 추가합니다.
  World.add(engine.world, box2);
}, 1400);
 
// 아까 위에 선언한 Matter에서 지정되어 있는 이벤트 인데요.
// 그중에 'collisionStart'은 오브제 간 충돌의 시작한 시점의 이벤트입니다.
Events.on(engine, "collisionStart", (event) => {
  // 오브제들이 충돌하면 console.log를 출력합니다.
  console.log('collision');
});
// 첫번째 글이라 자세히 적진 않았지만 인자로 받은 event의 값으로
// 충돌한 오브제 A와 오브제 B를 구분하여 이벤트를 처리해 줄 수도 있습니다


</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove every single object from the scene, matter.js makes that easy, since it keeps a list of all the objects.

`engine.world.bodies.forEach((body)=>{Matter.Composite.remove(engine.world, body)})`

If you want to remove many objects but not literally all of them, you'll have to keep track of your own list of objects to-be-removed as you create them, and then iterate through that list instead.

Answer (score 0):

[`World`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/World.html) has been deprecated:

> This module has now been replaced by `Matter.Composite`.
>
> All usage should be migrated to the equivalent functions found on `Matter.Composite`. For example `World.add(world, body)` now becomes `Composite.add(world, body)`.
>
> The property `world.gravity` has been moved to `engine.gravity`.
>
> For back-compatibility purposes this module will remain as a direct alias to `Matter.Composite` in the short term during migration. Eventually this alias module will be marked as deprecated and then later removed in a future release.

Here's a minimal sketch of [`Matter.composite.clear`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Composite.html#method_clear) to clear the bodies.

If you need more control to remove a specific body, or a subset of bodies, you can use [`Matter.Composite.remove(engine.world, body)`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Composite.html#method_remove).

```js
const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
const render = Matter.Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine,
});
Matter.Runner.run(engine);
Matter.Render.run(render);
const addBodies = () =>
  Matter.Composite.add(engine.world, [
    Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
      400, 210, 810, 60, {isStatic: true, angle: 0.0}
    ),
    ...Array(50).fill().map(() =>
      Matter.Bodies.circle(
        Math.random() * innerWidth, 0,
        Math.random() * 30 + 10
      )
    ),
  ]
);
addBodies();
document.addEventListener("click", () => {
  Matter.Composite.clear(engine.world);

  // Or to remove each body one by one, or specific bodies:
  //engine.world.bodies.slice()
  //  .forEach(e => Matter.Composite.remove(engine.world, e));

  addBodies();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.js"></script>
<div>click to reset</div>
```